# After a git reset --soft HEAD^ was performed, how do I remove files not needed by my repo?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-commit, source-control-explorer, unstage

I had to run

> git reset --soft HEAD^

to undo a commit with large files ([same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70088051/after-upgrading-from-angular-12-to-13-cache-is-too-large-for-github)).
Now I can see my files again in VS Code Source Control Explorer(see below)

**Problem** - I want to remove these files from being added to my repo when committing and then pushing, so I added

> /.angular/cache

to my .gitignore file, but that didn't remove the files from the Source Control window.

**Question** - Do I need to do something else to remove these files from Source Control? ex. unstage each file individually

Source Control in VS Code:

[image]

Comment: They're staged to be commited - unstage them _and_ add them to `.gitignore`

Comment: `git reset --soft` "undoes" the commit, but leaves the corresponding changes staged. Is there are reason you didn't use `git reset --mixed` (or just `git reset`; `--mixed` is the default)?

Comment: I followed the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71562755/1186050, who said to use --soft HEAD^. Not sure it's it's right, not that familiar with git.

Comment: That answer also says "you can get rid of your large files and commit again". Do that with `git rm --cached -r --force .angular/cache`. This will unstage the files, but not remove them from your disk.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR Summary

As [chepner suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563851/after-a-git-reset-soft-head-was-performed-how-do-i-remove-files-not-needed-b#comment126482337_71563851), you probably really *wanted* a `--mixed` reset, not a `--soft` reset.  However, as [j6t added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563851/after-a-git-reset-soft-head-was-performed-how-do-i-remove-files-not-needed-b#comment126482785_71563851), you can recover from this error by using `git rm --cached -rf .angular/cache` (be sure to use the `--cached` to avoid removing the working tree copies).

You will still want to create or update your `.gitignore` so that you can't *accidentally* add the `.angular/cache` contents again.  You should `git add` the file after updating it (or creating it with appropriate initial contents).

Had you used `--mixed` (or the default which *is* `--mixed`), you might have had to add some *other* files besides the `.gitignore`, but you could update the `.gitignore` file first, then use a standard "add everything" (`git add .`) to add everything except the current untracked-and-ignored files.  This tends to be *easier to get right*, which is why it's the recommended method.  But adding everything, then un-adding (`git rm --cached -rf`) the unwanted files, also works.  It's just klunky and easy to get wrong.

## Necessary background (long)

Git is all about *commits*.  Git is not about *files*, although Git commits hold files, and Git is not about *branches*, although Git branch names help you (and Git) *find* the commits.  As such, you need to know what a Git commit is and does for you, and how `git commit` makes a *new* commit.  So let's touch lightly on commits first.

#### A Git commit is ...

A Git *repository* is, at its heart, just two databases.  One database hold *commits and other supporting objects*, and a separate database holds names—branch names, tag names, and other names that help Git find the commits.  It's the commits-and-other-objects database that really matters: you can use a repository in which the names database is completely empty (it's just extremely awkward and unpleasant to do that), but you can't use a repository in which the objects database is empty.

Ignoring the supporting here, we'll just talk about the commit objects, since those are the ones you interact with.  All the objects, including the commits, are *numbered*, but their numbers are big ugly random-looking things, such as [<sup><sub>`f01e51a7cfd75131b7266131b1f7540ce0a8e5c1`</sub></sup>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f01e51a7cfd75131b7266131b1f7540ce0a8e5c1).  The *commit* hash IDs are always totally unique.  So if you have this commit (the one that starts with `f01e51a7cf`, that I linked to the GitHub copy of it), it's literally *this* commit, and you must have a clone of the Git repository for Git.  The need for these numbers to be totally unique to each commit is what makes them so big; it also makes them unusable by humans, but the computer is good at them, so the *computer* uses them.  We use branch names instead, as we'll see in a moment.

The numbering system requires that nothing ever be changed once it gets stored.  So the big all-objects-database you find in a Git repository is completely read-only; all you ever do is *add* to it.<sup>1</sup>

Besides being numbered, each commit:

- Holds a full snapshot of every file, in a compressed and (important for Git's internal operation and for your disk space needs) *de-duplicated* fashion.  That is, when you make a new commit, if you have a million files but have only changed *three* of them, the new commit doesn't duplicate all 1 million files: it re-uses all but the new three.

  These snapshots are like tar or WinZip archives, in a way, in that you can just have Git extract all the files from them any time you like.  But they're not ordinary files: they're special Git-only compressed-and-de-duplicated things, that only Git can read, and nothing—not even Git itself—can overwrite.  That's why they are safe to share across multiple commits.
- Holds some metadata, such as the name and email address of the person who made the commit.  Your log message goes in here too, when you make a commit.  Crucially for Git's internal workings, Git adds, to this metadata, a list of *previous commit* hash IDs, which Git calls the *parents* of this commit.

Most commits just have a single parent.  That is, most commits list one previous commit hash ID.  This results in a simple backwards-looking chain.  Suppose `H` stands for the hash ID of your newest commit.  We'll draw this with an arrow coming out of it, indicating that `H` *points to* its parent commit (by storing the hash ID of the parent):

```
            <-H
```

We'll call the parent commit hash ID `G` for short, and draw in commit `G`:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Of course, `G` is a commit too, so it has a list of parents; it's a typical commit, so it has just one parent, which we'll call `F`, and we'll draw in `F`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

`F` is a commit, with a parent, so it points back still further, and so on.  By following this chain backwards, one commit at a time, Git can find *every* commit in the chain, all the way back to the very first commit ever.  That commit (presumably `A` in our simple example here) has an *empty* list of parent commit hash IDs, so that it doesn't point backwards at all, and that lets `git log` stop going backwards.

So that's how `git log` shows you the history.  **The history is nothing but the commits.**  The commits are the history; `git log` starts wherever you are now (usually at the latest) and works backwards, one commit at a time.

There's just one nasty little problem right now, and that is: to use this, we'd have to memorize at least *one* Git commit hash ID.  How are we going to find commit `H`?  How will we know it's the *latest* commit?  This is where the branch names come in.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git will occasionally stick "junk" in here, and will clean it out on its own later.  Calling it append-only is therefore a bit wrong technically.  But unless you have truly enormous files (petabytes at a time) or are on ridiculously tiny storage quotas, you don't normally have to worry about this.

---

#### Branch names help you find commits

Let's draw our little diagram without bothering with the arrows this time (out of laziness):

```
...--G--H
```

We need a way to quickly *find* the random-looking hash ID `H`.  We'll have Git store that hash ID in a *branch name*, like `main` or `master`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

That is, the *branch name* `main` will hold the raw hash ID of commit `H`.  We won't have to remember it ourselves: we'll have *Git* do that job, by having Git store the hash ID of `H` under the name `main`.

If we create another new branch name:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, main
```

then, right now, both names point to the *same commit*.  But this is about to change, so now we need to know which of these names we're actually *using* to find commit `H`.  Let's say we use `git switch develop` or `git checkout develop`, so that we're using the name `develop`, not the name `main`, to find commit `H`; we'll draw that like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

#### New commits, part 1: What happens with branch names

Without (yet) explaining how Git goes about making the *snapshot* for a new commit, let's say we now make a new commit, which gets a new, totally-unique, big ugly random-looking hash ID, which we'll just call `I` so that we don't have to guess it.

Commit `I` will store a single snapshot of all files, plus some metadata.  In the metadata for `I`, Git will add our name and email address, our log message, the current date-and-time, and—so that history works—Git will set the (single) parent of new commit `I` to be existing commit `H`.

Git knows to use that hash ID because the name `develop`, to which `HEAD` is attached, *currently* points to commit `H`.  That is, we're on `develop`, and `develop` *means* "commit `H`", so new commit `I` should point back to existing commit `I`.  Git writes out the new commit metadata-and-snapshot and now we have:

```
          I
         /
...--G--H
```

**Now Git does its sneaky trick.**  The name `main` pointed to `H` before, and still does.  But Git, having allocated a new hash ID to new commit `I`, makes the *current* name point to `I` now:

```
          I   <-- develop (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

So now if we use the name `develop`, we get commit `I`, and if we use the name `main`, we get back to commit `H`.  If we make another new commit, we'll have `develop` pointing to the newest such commit, which will point backwards to now-existing commit `I`, which will continue (forever) to point backwards to existing commit `H`, and so on:

```
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

Note that commits up through and including `H` are on *both branches*, in Git's reckoning.

#### New commits, part 2: Where does the snapshot come from?

We noted above, at the beginning of this, that all Git commits are permanent (well, mostly<sup>2</sup>) and read-only (completely).  Moreover, nothing can write to the *files* in a commit, and only Git itself can even *read* those files.  So how are we ever supposed to get any work done?

The fact that the snapshot in a commit is like an archive gets us the first part of the answer.  To *check out* a commit (with `git checkout` or `git switch`), Git will *extract the archive*.  That is, Git will de-Git-ize and de-compress the data for each file and store it in an *ordinary* file: one the computer can read and write as usual.  *All the programs on your computer* can deal with *these* files, as they're literally *ordinary files*.

These files go into what Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  It's literally where you do your work.  You don't work on/with the files that are *in* Git.  You work on files that *aren't* in Git, that are instead extracted to your work area.  Almost all version control systems (VCSes) work this way, for the simple reason that the VCS-ized *saved* files are in some internal format.

If Git were like most other version control systems, we'd stop here, with the two copies of each file from the current commit: one stored forever inside the commit, and one usable one.  You'd work on the usable files and then use the "make new commit" action and Git would make the new commit from the updated files.

**Git isn't like this.**  Instead, Git has another trick up its sleeves.<sup>3</sup>  Instead of keeping *two* copies of each file—the committed one, and the working one—Git keeps *three* copies of each file.  Or rather, three "copies": in between the committed copy and the working copy, Git keeps an extra "copy", stored in the compressed-and-de-duplicated *format*, but *not* read-only.  Because it's de-duplicated, this copy is initially *shared with* the committed copy.  The de-duplication is invisible though, so we don't have to worry about it: we can just *think* of it as a third copy.

In other words, instead of just:

```
HEAD commit                  working tree
-----------                  ------------
Makefile                     Makefile
README.txt                   README.txt
main.py                      main.py
```

we have a third copy of each file, in what Git calls—in Git-y fashion—by three different names: the *index*, or the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*.  All three names refer to the same thing, and I'll use the name *index* here, but *staging area* is closer to the way you mostly use it, so feel free to use that name in your head:

```
HEAD commit      index       working tree
-----------    ----------    ------------
Makefile       Makefile      Makefile
README.txt     README.txt    README.txt
main.py        main.py       main.py
```

When you change the *working tree* copy, *nothing happens to the index copy*.  You must run `git add` regularly; the `git add` command means *make the index copy match the working tree copy*.  Git will, at `git add` time, *read* the working tree copy, *compress* it into the Git format, *check for duplicates*, and then:

1. if it's a duplicate: toss out the index copy (if there is one: if it's a new file name, there isn't an index copy here) and put in the duplicate;
2. if it's not a duplicate: toss out the index copy (if there is one) and put in the compressed form

and now either way, the index copy of the named file matches the working tree copy (and is pre-de-duplicated).

This means that the index copy is, *at all times*, ready to go into the *next* commit.  Thus, **what's in the staging area is what will go into the next commit**.  It is, in effect, the *proposed next commit*.  You edit files in your working tree just to edit them, and then **you use `git add` to update your proposed next commit**.

---

<sup>2</sup>A commit that you can't *find* will eventually go away for real.  We'll see that in a bit when we talk more about `git reset`.

<sup>3</sup>What kind of shirt or whatever does Git wear anyway?

---

#### New commits: summary

Since the index holds, at all times, the *proposed next commit*, all `git commit` has to do is:

1. gather all the metadata needed, including the *current* commit hash ID;
2. write out whatever is in Git's index *right now* as the new *snapshot:* it's pre-de-duplicated and ready to go;
3. store the new commit, obtaining the new unique hash ID; and
4. update the *current branch name* so that the new commit is the last commit on that branch.

Let's use our sample repository, which at this point looks like this:

```
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

and watch the action as we `git switch main` or `git checkout main`, make a *new branch name*, switch to that new name, and then make a new commit:

1. `git checkout main` or `git switch main`: this

   - removes (from index and working tree) the current commit's files (the files from `J`);
   - extract the `main`-commit's files (from `H`) into index and working tree; and
   - leaves us with this:

     ```
               I--J   develop
              /
     ...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
     ```
2. `git checkout -b feature` or `git switch -c feature`: this

   - creates a new branch name `feature` pointing to `H`;
   - switches to it: this would involve removing files from `H` and installing files from `H`, but Git sees that that's pointless and skips it;
   - leaves us with this:

     ```
               I--J   develop
              /
     ...--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD), main
     ```
3. We now modify some files in the working tree.  Nothing happens to Git's index yet, but then we run `git add` on those files, and now the versions in the index of the `add`-ed files match.

   If we like, we can create *new* files from scratch, and add those.  Or we can completely remove a file entirely, with `git rm`: that removes it from *both* the working tree *and* the index.
4. Now we run `git commit`.  Git packages up whatever is in the index *right now* and makes a new commit that updates the *current branch name*, i.e., `feature`, so we end up with:

   ```
             I--J   develop
            /
   ...--G--H   <-- main
            \
             K   <-- feature (HEAD)
   ```

Note how `git commit` simply *adds on* to the drawing.  No *existing* commit changes.  If commit `H` has some files in it that we *removed* when we made `K`, that just means that commit `K` lacks those files.  They're still there *in* commit `H`.  **It's the commits that matter.**  The commits hold the files.  Find the commit, check it out, and you'll get the files.

#### `git reset`

With all the above in mind, we can now understand what `git reset` does—or at least, what `git reset --soft`, `git reset --mixed`, and `git reset --hard` do.  The `git reset` command is very big inside and can do a lot of *other* things too, if you want it to; we are only going to cover the basic three here.

Suppose we have made another commit:

```
          I--J   develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

and we suddenly realize that commit `L` was terrible for some reason: wrong snapshot, bad commit message, whatever.  We have several options, but the easiest one is to use `git commit --amend`.  This command is a lie: it doesn't *change* commit `L`, it just makes a new commit `L'` that has commit `K` as its parent:

```
          I--J   develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L'  <-- feature (HEAD)
           \
            L
```

Commit `L` *still exists*.  We just *can't find it any more* because we use the *names*, not the hash IDs.  The name `feature` now finds the "amended" commit `L'`, not the original `L`.  But we won't talk here about using `git commit --amend`; instead, we'll talk about using `git reset`.

The `git reset` command works by letting us *move the current branch name*.  We can pick *any* commit, and make the name `feature` *point to* that commit.  For instance, we could pick commit `G` if we wanted to.  But let's pick commit `K`, using `HEAD^` or `HEAD~` to find it.<sup>4</sup>  *Any* of our three `git reset` commands, given the hash ID of commit `K` or a name that *finds* the hash ID of commit `K`, will do this:

```
          I--J   develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K  <-- feature (HEAD)
           \
            L
```

Commit `L` *still exists*, but the name `feature` now points to commit `K`:

- If we use `git reset --soft HEAD^`, Git moves the branch name, and then stops: the index and working tree are still from commit `L`.
- If we use `git reset --mixed HEAD^` or `git reset HEAD^` (the default `--mixed`), Git moves the branch name, yanks all the commit-`L` files *out* of the index, and inserts into the index all the commit-`K` files.  Then reset stops here.
- If we use `git reset --hard HEAD^`, Git moves the branch name and yanks all the commit-`L` files out of the index *and our working tree*, and installs into the index *and our working tree* the commit-`K` files.

So this kind of `git reset` can do *up to three* things:

1. move the branch;
2. reset the index; and
3. reset the working tree too.

The flags tell it *when to stop:* `--soft` says to do step 1 and stop.  The default is to do steps 1 and 2 and stop.  The `--hard` flag tells it to do all three steps.

If we like, we can `git reset --hard HEAD`.  That tells Git:

1. move the branch: find the current commit, to which the branch points now, and move the branch to point to the current commit;
2. reset the index; and
3. reset the working tree.

Because the commit we picked in step 1 is the commit the name *already points to*, the "move the branch" part was a no-op.  The name didn't actually move anywhere.  We used this `git reset` for its steps 2 and 3.  It still *did* step 1, it just didn't *achieve* anything by doing step 1.

We can use `git reset HEAD` to make Git do nothing during step 1 and then reset the index, without touching the working tree.  Note that if we leave out the commit hash ID—if we run `git reset` or `git reset --hard`—we get a mixed or hard reset that, in step 1, doesn't move the branch.  But we're always doing step 1, even if it's just a big nothing.

---

<sup>4</sup>This syntax—the suffix `^` or `~`—is part of a whole series of ways Git has of specifying commits.  Since the commit is the *raison d'être* of Git, there should be a lot of ways to name a commit, and there are.  See [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for a complete list of ways to name Git internal objects (mainly commits, but you can name the others as well).

---

#### Why the default `git reset` (i.e., mixed) is what you wanted

Using:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

you *would have:*

1. moved the branch name back one step, *and*
2. reset Git's index so that it holds the files from the selected commit; but
3. *not* reset the working tree (because `--mixed` suppresses step 3).

You could now `git add` each of the files you *want* to new or updated in the index, and *not* `git add` any files you *didn't* want updated in the index.  In other words, you could now do the same thing you normally do, all the time, with Git.

By using `git reset --soft HEAD^`, you did step 1, but not step 2.  So that meant you then had to adjust Git's index to *not* contain the files you *didn't want* to commit.  That's also something you will do now and then in Git, but it's less common than `git add`-ing files that you *do* want to commit.  It's not harmful to do it "backwards", it's just easier to get wrong.

#### Addendum 1: why `git update-index --assume-unchanged` is wrong

Git always makes new commits from the files that are in Git's index.  As such, the `git status` command has, as one of its jobs, the job of telling you about files in your *working tree* that *don't* match the copies in Git's index.

That is, suppose you've modified three files from the contents they had earlier.  Then you ran `git add` on one of them.  Let's list what's in each of the three "active" copies of each file, with a version number added.  You started with:

```
HEAD commit      index       working tree
-----------    ----------    ------------
Makefile(1)    Makefile(1)   Makefile(1)
README.txt(1)  README.txt(1) README.txt(1)
main.py(1)     main.py(1)    main.py(1)
```

After modifying all three files in the working tree, you have:

```
HEAD commit      index       working tree
-----------    ----------    ------------
Makefile(1)    Makefile(1)   Makefile(2)
README.txt(1)  README.txt(1) README.txt(2)
main.py(1)     main.py(1)    main.py(2)
```

Now you run `git add main.py`, forgetting to add `Makefile` and `README.txt`.  You get:

```
HEAD commit      index       working tree
-----------    ----------    ------------
Makefile(1)    Makefile(1)   Makefile(2)
README.txt(1)  README.txt(1) README.txt(2)
main.py(1)     main.py(2)    main.py(2)
```

One of the jobs of `git status` is to compare the index and working tree copies and **complain if they don't match**.  The result is a complaint that, hey, you forgot to `git add`those two files.

The index copy of each file has two special flags you can set:

- "assume unchanged"
- "skip worktree"

These two flags have different *purposes*, but both of them are currently implemented the same in terms of `git status`: they both make `git status` *not bother complaining* about the files when they don't match.

Running `git commit` at this point would make a new commit in which `main.py` is updated, but `README.txt` and `Makefile` are *not* updated.  In your case, the problem was that you added new `.angular/cache/*` files *to* Git's index.  Setting "assume unchanged" on those requires that there be *some* copy of *each of those files* **in** Git's index (you cannot set these flags on files that *aren't* in Git's index).  But you want each commit you make to *lack* these files entirely.  You want the files to *not be in Git's index*.

#### Addendum 2: about `.gitignore` files

Listing files in a `.gitignore` does not affect *whether* the files are *in* Git's index.  A file that is in Git's index *right now*, regardless of *why* it's there, makes that file a *tracked file*.  Git's `git status` command will (in the absence of assume-unchanged or skip-worktree) *complain about* files that are in Git's index and your working tree and don't match.  It doesn't matter whether these files are listed in a `.gitignore` or not: the files are tracked, so they'll be in the next commit, so Git will complain if they don't match.

What listing files in `.gitignore` *does* do is *suppress* a *different* complaint.  Suppose you have some file `xyzzy` in your *working tree* right now.  (Maybe you made it by pasting something you wanted to remember into a file, with the intent of removing it as soon as you've taken care of whatever it is.)  Suppose further that this file *isn't* in Git's index—it won't be in your next commit—and it *shouldn't* be in your index commit, or any commit.  Its presence in your working tree, though, will make `git status` complain that `xyzzy` is an *untracked file*.

An untracked file is, by definition, any file that exists in your working tree, but not in Git's index.  (Any file that *is* in Git's index is a *tracked* file.)  And `git status` complains about these, and you can't set any index-entry flags *for* these because they're *not in Git's index* **on purpose**.  So there needs to be a way to *stop `git status` from complaining*—and *that's* the first part of what a `.gitignore` entry does.

Listing a file name or pattern in a `.gitignore` tells `git status`, *hey, shut up about these files when they're untracked, I don't want to hear it, it's on purpose*.  To help out with `git add`, listing those files *also* means *and when they're untracked, if I use an en-masse "add all files" command like `git add .`, don't add them either*, and that's the second part of what a `.gitignore` entry does.

What all this means is that `.gitignore` is the wrong name for the file.  It should be `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-files-when-they-are-untracked-and-do-not-auto-add-them-with-en-masse-git-add-commands-either`.  But that's a ridiculous name to type, so `.gitignore` it is.

## Summary: what you've learned

- Git stores *commits*.  These store files and metadata.
- Git *finds* commits by hash ID, but humans don't do that, so Git saves hash IDs in names: a branch name holds *one* hash ID.
- Git finds commits by looking at commits, which point to earlier commits.  That's history, and is also how branches work: the branch name points to whichever commit we want to say is the *latest* commit.
- Git builds *new* commits from whatever is in Git's *index* aka *staging area*.
- The files you work on, in your working tree, are *not in Git*.
- You may want some files that are in your working tree *never to go into a commit*.  To make that happen, don't add them.  To make *that* **easier**, use `.gitignore` files, but be aware that that's not sufficient on its own: you have to make sure you haven't *already* added them.
- The `git reset` command moves the current branch name and then optionally resets the index and the working tree.
- Moving a branch name can cause a commit to become un-find-able (unless you've memorized its hash ID).

The last part is what makes `git reset` a dangerous command: if you can't *find* a commit, what good is it?  Also, `git reset --hard` erases stuff from your working tree, and working tree files *are not in Git*.  They may have come *out* of a commit (in which case you can get them again, from what same commit), but they may not have (e.g., if you spent all day updating them and haven't committed yet).

Comment: Hi Torek. what's the difference between a --soft and a --mixed reset? Also, I didn't use any rm --cached -rf .angular/cache. I just unstaged the files from that folder, then re pushed. I don't know if there'll be any consequence later on?

Comment: `--soft` means *do not touch index / staging area*, and `--mixed` means *reset index / staging-area*. (I'll add more to the answer, although this is explained in many other SO answers as well.) You said you "unstaged the files", but you didn't mention any command(s) that would do that, such as `git reset` or `git rm --cached`; now you say you did not use `git rm --cached`, so did you use an additional `git reset`?

Comment: I have bookmarked this answer to read it and absorb it over time. "the new commit doesn't duplicate all 1 million files: it re-uses all but the new three."  Does this not apply recursively? In the 3 modified files, it does not store these 3 files afresh, but only their diff patches which could be a lot smaller than the file itself?

Comment: "if it's not a duplicate: toss out the index copy" if a newly git added file did not exist in the index before, there is no index copy to toss out. Am I missing something?

Comment: "Or we can completely remove a file entirely, with git rm: that removes it from both the working tree and the index." For a novice (like me), one can also just delete the file using the normal windows explorer/linux way (and not use git rm) in the working tree. Then, when you do the next git commit, git will notice that this file is missing (but was there in a previous commit) and remove this file from the next commit.

Comment: In your last two tree diagrams, is it not also true that unless you knew the SHAID of leaf nodes (commit L in both these diagrams), these two commits are going to be lost forever eventually when git cleans up unreachable commits? There is no named branch referring to it or to any of its child commits.

Comment: Or is it the case that if I knew the SHAID of even commits that are unreachable via named branches, can I perpetually access these commits without worrying about the host (GitHub) cleaning up these unnamed yet identifiable (via SHAID) commits?

Comment: On that first one (storing "patches"): at the *object* level, Git stores whole copies of files. However, objects can be stored either "loose" (zlib compressed only) or "packed" (zlib compressed after doing delta compression). The pack files' delta compression results in what you're thinking of—but it does not happen until later, when packing objects.

Comment: On the second: I'll tighten up the wording, it's "toss it out of the index if it's there" (the index entry is really just a file name, the hash ID, and a bunch of cache data, at least until we get into merge conflicts when it gets more complicated). On the third: if you `rm` a file, there's still an index copy and until you cause Git to discard the index entry, the file will continue to be in new commits. Note that `git add removed-file` winds up *removing* the index entry: "add" effectively means "make same".

Comment: On the last one: if an object is completely unreachable, `git gc` will remove it. Git*Hub*, however, will keep it: this is because GitHub shares objects across forks, and references from another fork are invisible locally. Git keeps "nominally deleted" objects alive for a while using *reflog entries*, which I didn't cover above for space reasons; the reflog entries eventually expire and *then* the objects really go away.

Answer (score 0):

Adding your files to .gitignore alone is not enough.

You should do this:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged <file_path>`

and add your files to `.gitignore`

If you want to do this to a directory, open that directory in your shell (using cd):

and execute this:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged $(git ls-files | tr '\n' ' ')`

Comment: I also unstaged them from source control. Why do I need update-index? And I had to unstage like ~100 files from .angular/cache, so how would that be done if I had to type in <file_path> for each of the ~100 files?

Comment: @user1186050 check my edit please. Make sure that execute that command inside the directory you want to assume unchanged.

Comment: Hi Alan. I'm a little confused. If I've reset --soft HEAD^ and then unstaged all files that I don't want to include, do I still need to run update-index? If yes, why, what does it do?

Comment: @user1186050 you only need to run update-index if these files existed in the history (they still exist behind your last commit), which appears to be your case. This is why unstaging is not enough, as they have already existed in previous commits.

Comment: Hi Alan. I don't believe these .angular/cache files existed in previous commits. I believe these files are part of the last commit only. Is there a command I can run to verify this before I run update-index?

Comment: Hi Alan. I think I'm still a little confused. When you say "behind your last commit" are you referring to the one I ran a reset on(which is now removed from git log)? or the one before that?

Comment: Using `update-index` here is wrong: you want the large files *out* of the index entirely.

Comment: @torek this will rewrite the entire commit history. Was avoiding it in case he's working with a team and have issues linked to each commit